# Clarification regarding disqualified income for Earned Income Credit (EITC or EIC)

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-conversion, eitc

I'm a graduate student with several kids. Right now I'm trying to leverage my temporarily diminished income by "backdoor" rolling-over my 401k account to a Roth IRA account, without inadvertently disqualifying myself for EIC. My understanding is that any amount I rollover will be counted as "income" for tax purposes--but what kind?

Specifically, for EIC, increases in income like "wages" increases the EIC for a certain range and decreases it for sufficiently high wages ([see here](https://www.taxpolicycenter.org/sites/default/files/4.4.5_-_figure_1.png)). (In my case, I'm assuming money from a stipend is similarly considered)

However, sufficiently high income of other types, e.g. more than $3,500 in "[investment income](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/individuals/earned-income-tax-credit/eitc-income-limits-maximum-credit-amounts)", can disqualify a person altogether. (Aside: It seems the money made from investments in retirement accounts does not count, since this is not counted in your AGI)

- **Since the money moved from a pre-tax 401k to a post-tax Roth IRA is considered taxable "income" (even if it had no return), would this be counted as disqualifying, "investment" income?** Would it alternatively be considered the same as "wages"? What if there were earnings?
- Presumably returns on 529 funds that were distributed would be considered investment income?

The "[investment income](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/individuals/earned-income-tax-credit/eitc-income-limits-maximum-credit-amounts)" on the IRS site presumably is "[disqualified income](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/32)" in the code.

Comment: The portion of 529 distributions that are earnings are reported and taxed as 'other' income on line 21 (now on schedule 1) -- and not 'investment income' -- only to the extent they exceed your qualified education expenses (tuition and fees, net of any other tax-free assistance). Distributions used for qualified expenses are not reported or taxed at all.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with a Fidelity representative and found that:

- It would count as income for my AGI based on their current market value, but not "investment" income (which I think is boxes 2b and 3b on 1040, plus maybe 1040 Schedule D).
- Note that 1) a sufficiently high AGI would disqualify you for EIC but otherwise 2) conversion "income" is neither "earned income" nor "investment" income.
- IRA positions could be converted directly to Roth IRA positions (i.e. without even selling them).

If the positions were sold, I still don't think they count as investment income, since they are being moved from one retirement account to another, and retirement accounts are considered differently.

Some related discussions below:

- https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=124178
- https://forum.mrmoneymustache.com/ask-a-mustachian/roth-conversion-and-eic/

Comment: Right. 401k and IRA conversions, and distributions also, go on line 4a and 4b and are income for general tax purposes but not 'investment income' for EITC. (Schedule D goes to line 13, now on schedule 1.)